# Is synchronize thread safe between multiple classes

Tags: java, multithreading, singleton

I have a multithread program. I have 2 singleton class with below structure:

```
public class A {
   public void synchronized method1() {
      B.getInstance().method2();
   }
}


public class B {
   public void method2() {
      doSomething();
   }
}
```

class `A` and `B` are both singleton and `method2` is not synchronized. I want to know if `method1` is thread safe ? I mean when one thread goes to `method2` through `method1`, can other thread enter `method1`?

Comment: Classes add nothing wrt. threading or thread safety. Different classes same methods; same class different methods - it doesn't change the rules. So what are the rules? And how do they affect the call graph?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If one thread enters `method1` then goes on to `method2` no other thread can enter `method1` until the first thread has returned from both `method2` and `method1`.

But keep in mind that multiple threads can execute `method2` concurrently (although at most one thread can come from `method1`).

So, is `method1` thread safe? Yes, but only if `method2` is thread safe as well.

Comment: so you mean i should mark method2 in class B synchronized?

Comment: That depends on what `method2` does, but then you would run the risk of have one thread enter `method1` and then have to wait for some other thread to finish executing `method2`. Perhaps that's fine. I can't tell.